# Using AMD OpenCL with mingw

Tags: c++, mingw, opencl, amd-app

I have downloaded and installed `AMD APP SDK 3.0`. When I try using it with mingw I get an error because `CL/cl.hpp` has `#include <intrin.h>` in it (this header is exclusive to VC++).

Is there a different set of header files for mingw? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I use both `MSVC` and `MinGw` 5.3.0 (bundled with `QtCreator`) to build `OpenCL` apps on both `Intel` and `AMD` Windows 10 systems using [AMD APP SDK 3.0](http://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) and I have never experienced a build problem that wasn't in my own code!

However, I use the *standard* **C** `CL/cl.h` header file, not the **C++** `CL/cl.hpp` header file...

The `cl.hpp` and `cl2.hpp` files provide **C++** bindings for the standard **C** functions, see [OpenCL C++ Bindings](http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/). If you don't require C++ bindings, the `AMD APP SDK 3.0` `CL/cl.h` header file works fine.

If you want to use `C++ Bindings` then note that `cl.hpp` is obsolete; you should use `cl2.hpp` instead (which doesn't try to include `intrin.h` unless `_MSC_VER` is defined)...

An alternative `OpenCL C++ binding` (that also compiles with `MinGw` and `AMD APP SDK 3.0`) is [boost compute](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/compute/doc/html/index.html).